update field workflow salesforce
I have an XX field in the account object that checks the number of opportunities related to that account. I created an XY field in the text rich case object.
Finally, I created a workflow rules and a field update. Which checks if the XX field is equal to 0, a red message appears if not a green message. This works but when I add an opp related to the account, that is, I make an update, it still shows the red message.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The WFR appears to be on a Case; it will only fire if DML occurs on a Case. From your description, it sounds like DML is occurring on the Opportunity and possibly rolling up to the Account (more DML).

So the update only occurs if it is in the case object?

BTW - Salesforce no longer supports Workflow Rules, so you should migrate to Flow.
